# How to simulate multiple dependent 2x2 tables?

Tags: chi-squared-test, simulation, independence, contingency-tables

I am doing a case-control study where we have a large number, say $N$ of 2x2 tables. For a single table we have fixed column totals, say $n_{+0}$ and $n_{+1}$ such that $n_{+0} + n_{+1} = n$, the total number of patients. Given the cell probabilities $p_{00},p_{11},p_{01},p_{10}$, we can simulate a 2x2 table by generating independently
$$Z_0 \sim binomial(n_{+0}, \frac{p_{10}}{p_{10}+p_{00}}), \quad
Z_1 \sim binomial(n_{+1}, \frac{p_{11}}{p_{11}+p_{01}})$$
and setting $n_{11} = Z_1, n_{10} = Z_0$, of course, $n_{01} = n_{+1}-n_{11}$ etc.

My question is, how do I simulate $N$ such tables where the tables are dependent? I am deliberately making this question a little vague as I am not sure what kind of dependence between two contingency tables seem reasonable. Of course we can make any reasonable assumption, like known row totals, to make it simpler.